# Using an Apache VirtualHost to access a Node JS instance on the same server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, node.js

I am using VirtualHosts to allow access to various domains and subdomians of my site on the same Apache server. Along the lines of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to have a specific subdomain pointing to a NodeJS server on the same server. I know I could use ProxyPass to forward to a different server, is there a similar way to do this with the same machine?

I assume I would have the Node server running on a port other than 80.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lets assume,

**Node.js running on `http://localhost:8000`**

```
<VirtualHost node.example.com:80>   
    ServerName node.example.com
    # with optional timeout settings  
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realise that ProxyPass could work for localhost. Derp!

Comment: Are there situations where this configuration also need the ```ProxyPassReverse``` directive?

Comment: "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request " why is that appeared once i used your solutions?

Comment: I got a node-red (node) server bound to port 443 already, and I'm trying to do this with another domain that will also utilize ssl ...  Will I need to move the port back to 1880 ? and use the ProxyPass method?

Comment: @mrSidX - yes, but it depends on how you want to route, the subdomain vs url paths. This example is for a hostname. If you want to host node-red behind a subpath, you;ll need to make sure that node-red supports this and you'll need to add the correct subpath rewrites for the website to load properly