# Running Node js app on subdomain of Apache 2.4 server

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js

I am trying to run a Node js app on port 8000, and have Apache 2.4.7 proxy a subdomain to that port on localhost. I'm able to get the node app served as a page ( http://example.com/nodeapp ) using a single VirtualHost, using a sites-enabled conf file like the one below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias "www.example.com"
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        ProxyPass "/nodeapp" "http://localhost:8000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

However, what I really want to do is have the node app run on a subdomain, like http://nodeapp.example.com, and this is where I'm having trouble. I've tried a bunch of different configurations with single and multiple VirtualHosts, but this is what my current one looks like:

```
<VirtualHost nodeapp.example.com:80>
        ServerName "nodeapp.example.com"
        # ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
        # ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias "www.example.com"
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is based on the question asked here:
[Using an Apache VirtualHost to access a Node JS instance on the same server](https://serverfault.com/questions/497856/using-an-apache-virtualhost-to-access-a-node-js-instance-on-the-same-server?newreg=fbe65b2abe44470884bbf5198482adcd)

However, when I go to the subdomain (which I setup on GoDaddy to just forward to the same server IP address), I just get a timeout, and if I look in the apache error log I see some lines like:

```
[Tue Mar 29 04:53:56.909467 2016] [core:notice] [pid 15912] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Mar 29 04:56:33.332390 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 15917] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (localhost) failed
[Tue Mar 29 04:56:33.332441 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 15917] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
```

I'm really not quite sure where I'm going wrong at this point, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that your Node.JS server is up properly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure because when I run the top configuration (with the node app on a page, not as a subdomain), node servers the page OK. It's just trying to get it working as a subdomain that's giving me problems.

Comment: `Connection refused` means that the port it is trying to connect to is not open, that is, there is no process listening to that port. So, the server is not running.

Comment: It was definitely running. I think I had my DNS screwed up at GoDaddy actually, which was part of the problem about why it worked as a page but not a subdomain, then added "Require all granted", and somewhere in there got it working...now I just need to figure out how to proxy websockets through too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName sub.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-sub.example.com.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-sub.example.com.log combined
    # sub:
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have another VirtualHost entry that you use for just regular example.com, not sub.example.com?